# Collapsing toolbar in activity, not desired behavior in all fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design

In my application, I decided to put the appbarlayout with the collapsing toolbar in my activity layout (which contains also a frame layout to change following the fragment). So there is no toolbar in any of my fragments.

The problem is that I don't want a collapsing toolbar in all my fragments. Sometimes I just want a simple "static" toolbar.

For example in my gifv  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFkZW.jpg  : I want the effect in "Our Packs" fragment, but not in the "My cart" one.

Do you have an idea how to remove the effect showed on the gif in "my cart" fragment ?

I have to say also that I cannot put the toolbar in each fragment for 2 reasons, the first is that I use the material design library to do my navigation drawer and it requires a toolbar in the mainActivity. And in second I think that's slower to change the toolbar each time I go in a different fragment.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You may disable nestedScroll on "My Cart" fragment's RecyclerView like:

`setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` since RecyclerView makes CollapsingToolbar expand and animate.

Comment: Okay problem half solved ! The collapsing toolbar doesn't expand when I scroll on the recyclerview but it does when I scroll on the toolbar oO

And doing  appbar.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); doesn't work ^^

Comment: AppBarLayout.setExpanded(false) may solve other half

Comment: It is not working (and it is said also that this feature is unavailable on api <21 and I work on >15)

What I observe also, which is really weird, is that If I scroll in "our packs"  fragment to expand the collapsing toolbar and after I go back in "my cart"  fragment to scroll  from the toolbar to try to expand it ,it doesn't work.
Like the bug is solved if I expand it from a  recyclerview. But if I restard the app I can again expand it from the toolbar :/

Comment: I dived into source code and find this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a6a508b/design/src/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.java#1233

Comment: CordinatorLayout controls every child's nested scroll property and it may be you can disable appbarlayout in case of "My Cart" is active fragment. `onStopNestedScroll(View target)`

Comment: I tried this :  

 appbar = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
        coordinatorLayout.onStopNestedScroll(appbar);

But nothing changed :'(

Comment: ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(null); this worked

Comment: thank you for you help I really appreciate it but I tried your solution but when I do that, the toolbar is fullly expanded like this : http://imgur.com/vGSzXSf